# I am trying to initialise a Base Class property of a Sub Class but I am getting an error in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to make this Sub Class Circle inherit the traits of parent class Shapes. I want the Circle Class to accept a colour string but I keep getting an error.

```
abstract class Shape  {
 def getArea():Double 
 var colour = "Red"

 def getColour():String = colour
 def setColour(newColour:String) = {
   colour = newColour 

 }
}

case class Circle (var radius:Int, override var colour:String) extends Shape {
  override def getArea():Double = 3.14 * radius * radius 
}
```

The error I get is:

"ScalaFiddle.scala:13: error: overriding field colour  in class Shape of type lang.this.String;"

Comment: A **case class** of mutable fields is broken by design and will cause you trouble later. A better approach to what you want to do would be something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/dmJLVZSzQsqQR3KrVppFsQ/3) _(however, returning the current type is, in general, a bit more complex, check [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type))_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override a `var` but you can assign to it.

```
case class Circle (var radius:Int, clr:String) extends Shape {
  colour = clr
  ...
```

BTW, mutable variables are dangerous. Just pretend that `var` doesn't exist. You'll write better code without it.

Comment: Im new to programming, which variable is mutable? is it var radius? Could you go into slighly more detail if possible please?  Regarding this "mutable variables are dangerous. Just pretend that var doesn't exist"

Comment: Everything declared as a `var` is mutable. Its value can be changed. A `val`, on the other hand, is immutable. Its value is set and never changed. It can be referenced with confidence that it hasn't been altered somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala the methods are usually overridden, not the variables. By default Scala doesn't allow it with *vars* (why? [here a simple and brief explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-field-overriding/)).

- **Option 1:**

In case you want to to force the compiler to allow so you must provide the Scala compiler the option `-Yoverride-vars`. Passing that option your code should compile and run properly.

- **Option 2:**

There is a trick: leave the abstract variable uninitialized.

Example:

```
sealed trait Shape {
  var colour: String
  def getColour: String = colour
  def setColour(colour: String): Unit = {
    this.colour = colour
  }
  def area: Double
}

case class Circle(radius: Int, var colour: String) extends Shape {
  override def area: Double = 3.14 * radius * radius
}
```

I know, it's strange this code works.

- **Option 3:**

A more idiomatic way with no need of special compiler option and keeping the code immutable:

```
sealed trait Shape {
  def colour: String
  def area: Double
}

case class Circle(radius: Int, colour: String) extends Shape {
  override def area: Double = 3.14 * radius * radius
}
```

The you can use the shapes in this way:

```
object Run extends App {
  val circle = Circle(10, "red")

  println(s"Circle area: ${circle.area}")
  println(s"Circle colour: ${circle.colour}")
  val circle2 = circle.copy(colour = "blue")
  println(s"Circle colour: ${circle2.colour}")
}
```

It will print:

```
Circle area: 314.0
Circle colour: red
Circle colour: blue
```

**#3** is the most idiomatic in Scala.